# Change Qt dial size in .ui file, PyQGIS plugin

Tags: pyqt

The main dialog in the plugin is entirely defined by an .ui file. No css stylesheet yet, nor processing (except for some values, not to define the controls).

I need a 2nd dial but its function is secondary/optional compared to the 1st, so I'd like to make it a little smaller, or maybe paler if smaller is not possible.

So far here is all I found: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-dial

But I'm not sure how to link the stylesheet to the .ui file. I understand you can even use images to customize controls, but I'd prefer not to, and keep it simple, starting from this:

```
      <widget class="QDial" name="dial_c">
       <property name="cursor">
        <cursorShape>ArrowCursor</cursorShape>
       </property>
       <property name="minimum">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="maximum">
        <number>360</number>
       </property>
       <property name="singleStep">
        <number>1</number>
       </property>
       <property name="pageStep">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="value">
        <number>180</number>
       </property>
       <property name="sliderPosition">
        <number>180</number>
       </property>
       <property name="tracking">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="invertedAppearance">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="invertedControls">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="wrapping">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="notchTarget">
        <double>90.000000000000000</double>
       </property>
       <property name="notchesVisible">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
```

How to do just the same, but smaller, ie 0.75x the default size?

Comment: The tool definition in the link is not a content of ui file, but qml file.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an .ui qml file. Trying to play with the numbers in your answer the dial stay the same size as the other dials, only this one is down a bit, even with 0 for x and y... Maybe the other elements and the main grid layout interfere with the geometry, or it's Windows 10... Only trick I have now is to set a larger rowspan for the big dial vs the smaller but the proportion is not constant when the dialog is resized (I removed that rowspan difference to test the 'geometry').

Comment: But the text in the question is a .ui file content, not qml.

Comment: Yes the code in my question is some kind of xml (that's what I thought it may be called qml) The link for qml files os for the UI (user interface, not ui file, I'm always confused with these names) and I don't know how to use it. I'll have to stick to my rowspan trick for now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `geometry` property (default size: 50x64),

```xml
<widget class="QDial" name="dial_c">

 <property name="geometry">
  <rect>
   <x>100</x>    -> topleft
   <y>100</y>    -> coordinates
   <width>38</width>
   <height>48</height>
  </rect>
 </property>

 ...
 ...
```

or

`styleSheet` property:

```xml
<widget class="QDial" name="dial_c">

 <property name="styleSheet">
  <string notr="true">qproperty-geometry: rect(100 100 38 48);</string>
 </property>

 ...
 ...
```

Comment: I will accept that answer although in my case I still need to wrap <item rowspan=... with different values around the dials to display different sizes. This explains how to use geometry and stylesheet properties and works well with other widgets in my form, so thanks!